# Dynamic division operation with groupby in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset composed of two columns: ID and TARGET. The TARGET column is composed of binary numbers ranging from 0 to 1. In the TARGET column, there is always a succession of 6 (or less than 6) numbers one, followed by any number of zeros.

What I need to do is add another column named PERCENTAGE that will identify the succession of ones and perform a division of 100/6, which will populate each cell of the new column with the result of the division, and each following cell will add the previous values. So the result must be like this:

| ID | TARGET | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 16 |
| A | 1 | 33 |
| A | 1 | 50 |
| A | 1 | 66 |
| A | 1 | 83 |
| A | 1 | 100 |
| A | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 |

My problem comes from the fact that when table begins with a succession of less than 6 ones, the division ends before reaching the number 100 in the PERCENTAGE column, looking like this:

| ID | TARGET | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 16 |
| A | 1 | 33 |
| A | 1 | 50 |
| A | 1 | 66 |
| A | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 |

But what I actually wanted to achieve is a column named PERCENTAGE that behaves like this when the table begins with a succession of less than 6 ones:

| ID | TARGET | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 50 |
| A | 1 | 66 |
| A | 1 | 83 |
| A | 1 | 100 |
| A | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 |

That is, I need column PERCENTAGE to always end up with 100 even if the succession of ones in the TARGET column is smaller than 6.
The code I've tried so far is this:

```
def verify(df):
   df['PERCENTAGE'] = (df.groupby(df['TARGET'].eq(0).cumsum()).cumcount() * 100 / 6).astype('int')
   return df
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `ID` column in your example if you show only a single value ? You can make your example more meaningful by providing a second id and mostly (*for brevity*) make it minimal by asking for a streak of two or three *1s* instead of six. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If the percent values are set from the beginning, start by defining them outside the transformation:

```py
MAX_ONES = 6
PCTS = [int((100 / MAX_ONES) * n) for n in range(1, MAX_ONES + 1)]
# PCTS = [16, 33, 50, 66, 83, 100]
```

Then one approach is to just index from that list:

```py
df["PERCENTAGE"] = df.groupby(["ID", "TARGET"])["ID"].transform(lambda x: PCTS[-len(x):])

# Set percent to zero where TARGET = 0
df["PERCENTAGE"] *= df["TARGET"]
```

Comment: It seems to be a nice approach, but every time I try to implement, I get the following error:

Value Error: Lenght of values (6) does not match the lenght of index

Comment: That could happen if there are more than 6 ones in a row. Could you provide the data it fails on? What's the number at the end of the error (e.g. `ValueError: Length of values (6) does not match length of index (7)`)?

Answer (score 0):

I introduce here a general case assuming you have several different `ID`. Let's suppose we have the following dataframe :

```
df
   ID  TARGET
0   A       1
1   A       1
2   A       1
3   A       1
4   A       1
5   A       1
6   A       0
7   A       0
8   A       0
9   B       0
10  B       1
11  B       1
12  B       1
13  B       1
14  B       0
15  B       0
16  B       0
17  B       0
```

**Proposed code**

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {'ID': ['A']*9 + ['B']*9,
        'TARGET': [1]*6 + [0]*4 + [1]*4 + [0]*4}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def percent(g):
    g['PERCENTAGE'] = g['TARGET'] * 100 / 6
    g['PERCENTAGE'] = g['PERCENTAGE'].cumsum()
    g['PERCENTAGE'] = g['PERCENTAGE'].add(100 - g['PERCENTAGE'].max())
    g['PERCENTAGE'] = g['TARGET'] * g['PERCENTAGE']
    return g

r = df.groupby(['ID'], group_keys=False).apply(percent)
print(r)
```

**Display**

```
   ID  TARGET  PERCENTAGE
0   A       1   16.666667
1   A       1   33.333333
2   A       1   50.000000
3   A       1   66.666667
4   A       1   83.333333
5   A       1  100.000000
6   A       0    0.000000
7   A       0    0.000000
8   A       0    0.000000
9   B       0    0.000000
10  B       1   50.000000
11  B       1   66.666667
12  B       1   83.333333
13  B       1  100.000000
14  B       0    0.000000
15  B       0    0.000000
16  B       0    0.000000
17  B       0    0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which creates a function, `f`, to calculate the percentages with `numpy`:

```
def f(x):
    v = np.cumsum(100/6 * np.ones(6))
    z = np.zeros(len(x))
    last1 = np.argmin(x.diff())  # index of the last 1
    z[:last1] = v[-last1:]
    return z 

df['PERCENTAGE'] = df.groupby('ID')['TARGET'].transform(f)
```

Output:

```
  ID  TARGET  PERCENTAGE
0  A       1   50.000000
1  A       1   66.666667
2  A       1   83.333333
3  A       1  100.000000
4  A       0    0.000000
5  A       0    0.000000
6  A       0    0.000000
```